# NotFoundHttpException in routeCollection.php LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

Hi have NotFoundHttpException in routeCollection.php in line 179.

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'MarketingController@home')->name('home');
```

[image]

[image]

Localhost:
htppd.conf

Comment: have you tried php artisan serve?? also to access it in that way you need to configure virtual host

Comment: Yeha, i tried in this way, but the same...

Answer (score 0):

In first time .env was:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

now:

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_URL=localhost
APP_DOMAIN=localhost
```

its ok!! Thansk!

Comment: what you did is exactly reverse of what i suggested i guess..anyways u have ur answer ..cheers

Answer (score -1):

Seems like it will help u or someone later,

In order to access the domains just like www.google.com on our local system for our local sites say `xyz.dev` we need to configure some settings for our system so here are they (Assuming you are using XAMPP or WAMPP stack on windows)

1. Open control panel and click on config right ahead of apache (or
   equivalent

server)

2. click Browse Apache a system window will be opened. navigate to
   conf\extra\
3. open `httpd-vhost.conf` file. add following (modify with your need)

   ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
       ServerName dummy-host.example.com
       ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
       ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
       CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
4. save file and close.
5. open your host file with admin privileges  here assuming on
   windows

(`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) file add your domain entry

```
eg
127.0.0.0 xyz.dev
```

6.Save file and close

7.restart apache

8.hit your domain in browser `xyz.dev`

Comment: Sorry, i try with this: `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@psicoreg.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\SOTECSA\Desktop\psicoreg\public"
    ServerName psicoreg.dev
    ServerAlias www.psicoreg.dev
    ErrorLog "logs/psicoreg.dev-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/psicoreg.dev-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: @AngelPrieto thats ok..its just a friendly note for other who might find it useful..